# Represent $\dfrac{\lambda_1^M-\lambda_2^M}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$ in terms of $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, polynomials

I have a problem as follows: Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are roots of the equation $\lambda^2-a\lambda+b=0.$ It can be proved easily (by induction for example) that the quantity $$\dfrac{\lambda_1^M-\lambda_2^M}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$$ is a polynomial $P_M$ in $a,b$.

My question is: Can we write down a precise formula for $P_M$?
I found a recursive formula for $P_M$'s which reads $$P_{M+1}=aP_M-bP_{M-1},$$ however it seems to be not enough to answer my question.

Any hint or idea is appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If $\lambda_1 = re^{i\theta}$, $\lambda_2 = re^{-i\theta}$, then

$$\begin{cases}
a = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 2r\cos\theta\\
b = \lambda_2 \lambda_2 = r^2
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
r &= \sqrt{b}\\
\cos\theta &= \frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}
\end{cases}
$$
For integer $M > 1$,

$$P_M = \frac{\lambda_1^M - \lambda_2^M}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} = \frac{r^M\sin(M\theta)}{r\sin\theta} = r^{M-1}U_{M-1}(\cos\theta) = \sqrt{b}^{M-1}U_{M-1}\left(\frac{a}{2\sqrt{b}}\right)$$
where $U_n(x)$ is the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the second kind. 
This implies $P_M$ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $M-1$ in $a$ and $\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Only one point which does not convince me: what happens if $a > 2\sqrt{b}$?

Comment: @mapping If $a > 2\sqrt{b}$, then $r$ and $\theta$ becomes complex. If you want to avoid complex numbers in such case, you can replace sin and cosine by corresponding hyperbolic sine and cosine in the middle of derivations. but in the end, you will get the same polynomial.

Comment: You are right! I am very happy with that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Or more simply, as you mentioned as an easy proof, one has

$$ \frac{\lambda_1^M - \lambda_2^M}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} = \sum_{k=0}^{M-1} \lambda_1^{M-1-k} \lambda_2^{k} $$

Hence

$$\bbox[lightgreen,5px,border:2px solid green]{P_M(a,b) = \frac{1}{2^{M-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{M-1} \left(-a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}\right)^{M-1-k} \left(-a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}\right)^{k}}.$$

Comment: Thank you! It could be another solution.